# изменение сервером имени файла при скачке file_get_contents

Tags: php, кодировка

Парсинг удаленного XML файла. 
У клиента в XML часть картинок имеет кирилицу, по типу

```
https://site.ua/upload/Блузка Laura(2).jpg
```

и когда пытаемся получить его с помощью file_get_contents, - получаем ошибку, а в логах видим, что сервер курочит символы

```
https://site.ua/upload/\xc1\xeb\xf3\xe7\xea\xe0 Laura(2).jpg
```

Пытался менять кодировку строки - изначально она в UTF-8, у меня файл скрипта тоже - не помогало. менял локаль

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.UTF-8');
```

короче, ничего не помогает. у других клиентов таких проблем не возникало, хотя и имелись такого же рода ссылки.

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Сами заранее закодируйте строку перед запросом с помощью urlencode http://php.net/manual/ru/function.urlencode.php

Comment: не катит, тогда вся строка изменяется, и адрес по прежнему недоступен, получается такое
`https%3A%2F%2Fsite.ua%2Fupload%2F%D0%91%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0+Laura%282%29.jpg`

Comment: немного погорячился. закодировать только имя файла